# correlation of two ordinal variables in R

Tags: r, correlation, ordinal

I want to test the spearman correlation of two ordinal variables.

```
x=c(1,2,3)
y=c(4,3,6)
x=ordered(x)
y=ordered(y)
cor(x,y,methods="spearman")
```

I always get "Error in cor(x, y) : 'x' must be numeric"

what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two methods:

1. use `as.numeric`.

   ```
   x=c(1,2,3)
   y=c(4,3,6)
   x=ordered(x)
   y=ordered(y)
   cor(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), method="spearman")
   [1] 0.5
   ```

Note that this is *not* treating x and y simply as continuous numbers. It is treating them as ranks.

```
as.numeric(y)
[1] 2 1 3
```

This method will allow you to ignore NA values.

```
x=c(1,2,3, NA)
y=c(4,3,6, 7)
x=ordered(x)
y=ordered(y)
cor(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), 
    method="spearman", use="pairwise.complete.obs")
[1] 0.5
```

2. You can use the package `pspearman` which will handle the ordered factor.

   ```
   x=c(1,2,3)
   y=c(4,3,6)
   x=ordered(x)
   y=ordered(y)

   library(pspearman)
   spearman.test(x,y)


   Spearman's rank correlation rho

   data:  x and y
   S = 2, p-value = 1
   alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
   sample estimates:
   rho 
   0.5
   ```

Or if you want to reduce some of the output,  you could use:

```
spearman.test(x,y)$estimate
rho 
0.5
```

Comment: Again, my point is that x and y are both ordinal outcomes, which means they are not continuous... I know Spearman rank correlation can handle ordinal variables, but don't now how

Comment: My real problem has some missing values for both x and y, so ideally I want to stick to the cor() function which can specify "pairwise.complete.obs". I appreciate the  `pspearman` but it cannot handle the missing data case

Comment: @Sheldon  The first version using `cor` successfully ignores NA.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You had a few issues:

1. using ordered will create a factor, you can use `rank`
2. You had a typo, it should be `method=...` not `methods=...`

--

```
x=c(1,2,3)
y=c(4,3,6)
x=rank(x)
y=rank(y)
cor(x,y,method="spearman")
```

Comment: using sort will alter the data. Originally x=2 when y=3, but not x=2 when y=4

Comment: Also, the way you did is treating x and y as continuous variables, but the truth is they are ordinal...

Comment: @Sheldon then how about using rank?